# About Flink 1.11 Deployment and Setup

Tags: deployment, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I need to run a Flink job in production, I have just one machine (is not a cluster). I'm trying to setup my Flink job for production and do it in the best way possible, different as I have it right now (running as a java application `java -jar flink_job.jar`). I was reading in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/#deployment-targets that this deployment mode is only for testing or experimentations, so, for production I think that I should move to standalone cluster, but, in Standalone cluster deployment mode says that I need to setup one master and at least one worker. My question, that I have to run in production just for one node (master):

- What is the best way to run flink in production on my case?
- Can I have my master and worker in the same JVM as the same way that Local cluster does?

Please can someone clarify a little bit this for me? Thanks.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing (running as one java app) might be fine -- there's no particular reason why you must set up a cluster if this meets your needs. But by doing so, you are giving up a few things. In particular, if you care about automatic restarts in event of failure, that's not going to be easy to set up.